# is it possible to set the text on a command button as " Clear & Exit "

Tags: vb.net, vb6

while clearing doubts one of my junior ask me the question "is it possible to set the text on a command button as " Clear & Exit " ?

i replied that " it is not possible, because for command button's text the '&' is used to set the **key board shortcut**", is my answer is correct? **"is it possible to set the text on a command button as " Clear & Exit " ?**

i had tried the following code segments:

```
Button7.Text = " clear " & "&" & "Exit"
Button7.Text = " clear " & Chr(38) & "Exit"
```

good responses are appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible to set the text on a command button as " Clear & Exit "

try this

```
Button7.Text = "clear && Exit"
```

You can also use "&&" to display a single ampersand. Using this method, you could leave UseMnemonic with a value of True and place a single ampersand before another letter in the Caption to define an access key.

Comment: thanks for the information, thanks Mohit Shrivastava

Comment: Its always a pleasure serving.